# Can apartment switch to month-to-month and refuse Lease without consent?

Tags: washington, lease

I'm in dire straights atm regarding my apartment.

I reside in Washington State, and for two years now I've been leased to an apartment. We renewed the first year without issue. However, during the lease the ownership changed hands. This wasn't a problem until a few months ago when we awaited the new lease agreement. They told us they were experiencing "system issues" (as a Technician myself, that's lay-terminology for "we have no idea"), and we would receive a new lease shortly. Over the last few months we made several attempts to get the new lease, in the meantime they decided to switch to the Month-to-Month rate without telling us. This new rate is $4,000/month. This is just your standard two-bedroom apartment, it's most luxurious feature is that is isn't falling apart. Now they're demanding back-pay of up to $7,000 for the months they charged us the new rate.

Some quick facts:
We were under a lease. 
The lease was in for renewal.
We never received the lease agreement or notice of change to the rate or agreement.
They didn't change the online bill pay bill amount, it remained showing the original rate.
They have served us a 14-day notice to vacate, and still no lease.
We have documented proof that we requested and waited for a lease and had no notice of denial for a new lease, or change of any kind.

I'm not sure what I can do, law is entirely out of my professional and personal purview. I would greatly appreciate any help in the right direction, any indication that I have a way to fight this sudden dire situation. I recognize that any assistance rendered does not count as legal advice as a service rendered, in part or in whole.

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: What did you lease say in regards to a month-to-month rate?

Answer (score 1):

All lease changes must be communicated to you in writing: changes to month-to-month, changes in a new annual lease, anything. Not informing you of the switch to the month-to-month rate - either in the online system or in writing - is illegal. And demanding "back-pay" (back-rent?) $7,000 is probably illegal, as they didn't inform you of the lease change.

See [WashingtonLawHelp.org](https://www.washingtonlawhelp.org/resource/your-rights-as-a-tenant-in-washington) for good outlines of tenant law. If your income is too high to qualify for free help, ask them for a referral.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The resource you showed me should help greatly in my stand-off against this nonsense. It's greatly appreciated!